# java dicegolfgame - whileloop

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm stuck on this while loop question, would be glad if someone could spot out where I am going wrong :)

Golf game Write a program that uses a while loop to play a dice golf game. The distance to the hole starts at 100m. The person repeatedly chooses which club to use. The different choices each correspond to a different sided virtual ‘dice’ to roll – ie giving a random number. If they choose club 1 (a putter) they roll a number from 0-5 representing the distance hit. If they choose club 2 (for pitching) they roll a number from 0-30. If they choose club 3 (an iron) they roll a number from 0 to 150. After each roll that number is subtracted from the distance to the hole (with negative distances being made positive for the next round). They keep rolling until they get the distance to exactly 0. When they do the number of shots taken is printed.

```
The following shows an example run of the program:
Distance to hole 100m. Which club (1-putting, 2-pitching or 3-iron) 3
You hit it...120m
Distance to hole 20m. Which club (1-putting, 2-pitching or 3-iron) 2
You hit it...16m
Distance to hole 4m. Which club (1-putting, 2-pitching or 3-iron) 1
You hit it...1m
Distance to hole 3m. Which club (1-putting, 2-pitching or 3-iron) 1
You hit it...3m
Congratulations. You took 4 shots.
```

**I am new to java, below is what I managed to get done, but shows error on: while (input.equals !( "1" || "2" || "3") ). I'm not sure whether its done correctly and spent ages on this, would be glad if someone could help out on the question problem :) Much appreciated.**

```
public static void dicegolfgame(String[] args)
{

String input = "";
int difference = 0;
int newdistance = 0;
int distance = 0;
int i = 0;

while (input.equals ( "1" || "2" || "3") )
{
Random roll2 = new Random();
distance = roll2.nextInt(100);

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "distance to hole " + distance + " Which club (1-putting), 2-(pitching) or 3-iron");

while (difference > 0 && difference < 0)

if (input.equals ("1"))
{
Random roll = new Random();
newdistance = roll.nextInt(5);
i = i+1;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you hit ..." + newdistance + "m");
difference = distance - newdistance;
}

else if (input.equals ("2"))
{
Random roll = new Random();
newdistance = roll.nextInt(30);
i = i+1;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you hit ..." + newdistance + "m");
difference = distance - newdistance;
}

else if (input.equals ("3"))
{
Random roll = new Random();
newdistance = roll.nextInt(150);
i = i+1;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you hit ..." + newdistance + "m");
difference = distance - newdistance;
}

if (difference == 0)
{
break;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations, you took" + i + "shots.");
}
```

Comment: while (difference > 0 && difference < 0) - how is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure as i said i'm new to this but the questions asking the while loop to carry on even if the difference is negative, so I thought difference should be kept >0 and <0. I guess i'm wrong :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the distance to the hole that determines whether the golfer has to shoot again or not - so that should be in the while loop. I've added some comments in the code:

```
String input = "";
int distance = 100;
int numberOfHits = 0;
int hit = 0;

while (distance > 0) {
    numberOfHits++;//increasing the nuber of hits
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("distance to hole " + distance + " Which club (1-putting), 2-(pitching) or 3-iron");
    switch (input) {//if you don't know switch you coukd use if-else
        case "1":
            Random roll = new Random();
            hit = roll.nextInt(6);//a random int netween 0-5
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you hit ..." + hit + "m");
            distance -= hit;//sets the new distance to the old distance subtracted the hit
            distance = Math.abs(distance);//if distance is negative make it positive
            break;
        case "2":
            roll = new Random();
            hit = roll.nextInt(31);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you hit ..." + hit + "m");
            distance -= hit;
            distance = Math.abs(distance);
            break;
        case "3":
            roll = new Random();
            hit = roll.nextInt(151);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you hit ..." + hit + "m");
            distance -= hit;
            distance = Math.abs(distance);
            break;
    }
}
//when we are out of the loop the distance is zero
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations, you took " + numberOfHits + " shots.");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!! :D That made it really easy to understand, now it makes more sense. :) @NerosE